# Analyzing the impact on non standard monetary policy through event study

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, panel-data

I have collected bond yield data from 01/01/2008:31/12/2019 for several euro-zone countries. I would like to conduct an event study analysis of the main Non standard measures announced by central banks, but I am not sure which model is best from a theoretical point of view. I basically have dummy variables and control variables as regressors, that are the same for each countries, except for the first lags of the dependent variable.

Would you estimate the model for each country separately via OLS, or should I use a Panel estimation method? One of the main problem I face is that, bond yields were rising because of the sovereign debt crisis and many policies were announced on a period of turbulent markets so that I get for instance positive loadings on many non standard monetary policy announcements. How would you handle this issue?